# Creating a PostgreSQL Trigger for automatic updates. ERROR: column is not of a character type

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.3

I've been following the PostgreSQL docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-features.html) on how to create a trigger for automatic updates. The example I've been using is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    title       text,
    body        text,
    tsv         tsvector
);

CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON messages FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
tsvector_update_trigger(tsv, 'pg_catalog.english', title, body);
```

And everything works great.

The issue arises when I declare the body column to be an array like so:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    title       text,
    body        text[], 
    tsv         tsvector
    );
```

I then get the following error message on executing the above trigger command after I have updated a field:

```
ERROR: column "body" is not of a character type.
```

I'm able to update the table manually using the following command:

```
UPDATE messages SET tsv = to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title,'') || ' ' || coalesce(body::text,''));
```

I've tried to declare the body column as an array in the trigger command using `body::text`. However, this doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And where is the `tsvector_update_trigger` code ?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the error here is that your `tsvector_update_trigger` function doesn't accept a `text[]`, but expects a `text` instead. So if you were to update the function first, you would then be able to update the table and it would all work.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but there is an example for write your own trigger in the doc [12.4.3. Triggers for Automatic Updates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS):

```
CREATE FUNCTION messages_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new.tsv :=
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.title,'')), 'A') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.body,'')), 'D');
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON messages FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE messages_trigger();
```